# Form Data Not Being Sent From View To Controller

Tags: forms, cakephp-2.x

So I'm trying to send a few pieces of data from a form in cake's form builder but for some reason none of the data being submitted is showing up when I print out `$this->data` or `$this->request->data`

I've tried creating the form myself and using cake's Form Builder and I need to send this data via POST.  The data shows up if I send it as a GET parameter.

view.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->create(null, array('action' => 'downloadbgc', 'type' => 'get'));
echo $this->Form->input('userId', ['type' => 'text' , 'id' => 'userId', 'name' => 'userId', 'value' => $user->id]);
echo $this->Form->input('product_id', ['type' => 'hidden' , 'id' => 'product_id', 'name' => 'product_id', 'value' => $user->product_id]);
echo $this->Form->submit('Download PDF', array('class' => 'btn btn-icon btn-primary', 'title' => 'Download'));
 echo $this->Form->end();
```

controller.php

```
...
public function downloadbgc() {
    $this->autoRender = false;

    print_r("Data: ");
    print_r($this->data); die();
    }
}
...
```

When printing this out I get `Data: Array()` instead of `Array('userId' => X, 'product_id' => Y)` And I'm positive that these values aren't null since they print to the console.

Comment: It should work if you use POST, but not if you use GET. Please make sure you are refreshing the form view when making changes (not just `/controller/downloadbgc/`), and that `view()` and `downloadbgc()` are in the same controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use the FormHelper's create() in a correct way:

```
echo $this->Form->create(false, ['url' => 'downloadbgc']);
echo $this->Form->input('userId', ['type' => 'text' , 'id' => 'userId', 'name' => 'userId', 'value' => 123]);
echo $this->Form->input('product_id', ['type' => 'hidden' , 'id' => 'product_id', 'name' => 'product_id', 'value' => 4456]);
echo $this->Form->submit('Download PDF', array('class' => 'btn btn-icon btn-primary', 'title' => 'Download'));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Like the [Docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-forms) point out the `create()` method can take the Model as first parameter or *false*, if you want to access the data without Model. Also use the *url* option as *action* is deprecated

In your Controller you can then use `$this->request->data` to access your data.